# Concat two columns of mysql table in one serially?

Tags: mysql

I am working on autocomplete and I need data from two columns as one through mysql :

I have a table such as

```
id serial name
1  EHY    Audi
2  EHZ    Lemo
3  EHM    Ferrari
```

now i want the result to be in one table as i want my autocomplete to bring data from both serial and name fields like this

```
-list-
EHY
EHZ
EHM
Audi
Lemo
Ferrari
```

Can this be done in a single query call?

I used this query,(its just an example), I want something similar to this but binding data serially.

```
select concat(c.name, c.serial) as lising from data c
```

Comment: And what happened when you use the query?

Comment: @User016 It resulted as EHYAudi, EHZLemo, EHMFerrari which I didn't wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `UNION` syntax:

```
SELECT `serial` FROM `table`
UNION ALL
SELECT `name` FROM `table`
```

Comment: what will be the difference if I use union in place of union all, in both cases i am getting difference in list count, union gives me 68 results, whereas union all gives me 84, yet both columns have different type of data...

Comment: `union` is the shortform of `union distinct`so it removes double values. `union all` gives you the whole result

Answer (score 1):

Your CONCAT query must be output as [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef8a/2)

But that's not you want, so dont use `CONCAT`, you can get it by using **UNION**

Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ef8a/1) with list of data

```
SELECT serial AS list FROM table_name UNION SELECT name AS list FROM table_name
```